# How to Debug Wordpress hosted in Azure Web Site

Tags: wordpress, azure, website

I have a Wordpress site hosted in azure and configured with my domain and private certificate. Some time ago (I don't remember any changes, but I tend not to remember things) I started to get logged-out from the admin panel after a couple of minutes editing a post. This happens sporadically and I have been unable to see a good pattern that could explain the behavior.

I am not an expert in IIS or Azure Web Sites, but I have strong technical background, so I want to check why this problem is occuring, but I don't really know where to start. What logs should I be checking in the web site? What logging type(s) do I need to enable to get these logs? How do I access them?

Answer (score 1):

You can have access to many information by adding your url "scm". 
Example: namesite.scm.azurewebsites.net

Comment: And why should I do that?

Comment: It goes to the same place as the Advanced Tools page linked in Azure portal. I did not find it is easy though.